# Workflow not getting triggered in target library from drop off library in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, drop-off-library

I have associated a reusable workflow with a content type in the content type hub.

I am trying to use the workflow in another site collection for moving a document from one library to target library.

I am also using drop off library to upload the documents once it satisfies the rule it reaches a library where my workflow should trigger automatically, but it is not getting triggered.

If I edit the properties the workflow is getting triggered.

I tested the workflow by creating a normal document library and uploaded a document workflow is triggering properly.

In workflow creation I have checked all the three check boxes (Manual start, Automatic on item creation, Automatic start on change.)

Please suggest what should I do to make workflow to trigger automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The account used by the content organizer to route documents will not trigger workflows by design.  As a work around I created an regular document library as the drop off.  I used my custom content types in it and implemented a workflow to do the document routing (copy/delete).  The workflow in the target library will then trigger on create.